# Header Expires not working

Tags: header, apache2

In `httpd.conf` the last lines are:

```
ExpiresActive On
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 3 days"
</FilesMatch>
```

When I run YSlow it says all my CSS files (and others) do not have expiration set.  The CSS files are in subdirectories but I believe `"\."` should match all files regardless of subdirectory.

Apache is set up for virtual hosts, but the above directives are outside of vhosts section at the very bottom of `httpd.conf`.

There is a directive for `LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so` in the `.conf` file.

The site is on AWS running AWS Linux and Apache2.  I restarted apache before checking if it worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In answer to your question, this works for me in my httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule expires_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_expires.so
ExpiresActive On

<filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault "access plus 3 days"
</filesMatch>
```

Here are a few things to try:

1) Make sure mod_expires.so is where you think it is. You can see what modules are being included by using this in your terminal: `apache2 -M`.

2) Make sure your directives apply to the files you're interested in (i.e. not getting overwritten by a `.htaccess` file somewhere farther down the line)

3) Make sure the `LoadModule` directive is in your httpd.conf file

4) In your `FilesMatch` regex, you should escape the dot with a backslash otherwise you're matching any character. Not a big issue, but you'd end up applying the rule to non-static pages like `"site.com/politico"` (note the `ico` ending) for example.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I had everything right except the placement of the code( your item3).  I put it into the virtual host section for the site and presto yslow was happy!  Thanks again.