# Leverage browser caching on Amazon EC2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pagespeed

This is my first time using Amazon AWS for any hosting and I've uploaded my usual code, below, to help with browser caching and it seems that tools like GT Metrix and Google Page speed are not seeing it work.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas if I need to enable anything on Amazons side for this to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AWS EC2 is just a regular virtual server. If you directly hosting the application in EC2 you need to configure caching as you do in any other hosting. However if you use AWS Cloudfront in-front of EC2 for caching, then you need to configure it there properly.

Comment: Any resolution to this as suffering the same fate

Comment: Ahh yes! Will add my solution now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation it turned out that the Apache modules needed for this were not installed on our instance.

What you need to do is ssh into your server as a root user and run the following command

Check which modules are installed using this command

```
apache2ctl -M
```

and looking for `expires_module`. It's probably not there.

**enable browser caching**

```
sudo a2enmod expires
```

**restart apache**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Another great answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10845651/5223522